# How fast should internet speed be to host a webserver?

Tags: hosting, internet

We host our own linux webserver in house. The company's Internet connection speed is 100MB, and the server runs no problem with it. We are planning to have another webserver located in another place, where there's no internet connection yet. My question is, how fast should the internet speed be in order to host a webserver that has about 3000 visitors daily?

Our webserver is specified as this:

- Linux + PHP + mysql
- it's a webshop, with many database transactions.
- about 3000 visitors daily.
- we have experienced appr. 100 people online at the same time.